# Android room not returning anything with url as parameter

Tags: kotlin, android-room

I'm trying to access a list of Items by the primary key of Feed like so. The primary key is a url. Attempting to access it like this gives me null back, and attepting to put `:arg0` in quotes creates a compile time error `error: Unused parameter: arg0`. Is it possible to use a url for this query?

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM item WHERE feed_url = :arg0")
fun observeAllByFeed(feedUrl: String): LiveData<List<Item>>
```

Item

```
@Entity(foreignKeys = arrayOf(ForeignKey(
        entity = Feed::class,
        parentColumns = arrayOf("url"),
        childColumns = arrayOf("feed_url"))))
data class Item(
        @ColumnInfo(name = "guid") @PrimaryKey var guid: String = "",
        @ColumnInfo(name = "categoryIds") var categoryIds: List<Int> = emptyList(),
        @ColumnInfo(name = "comments") var comments: String? = null,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "content") var content: String? = null,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "description") var description: String = "",
        @ColumnInfo(name = "author") var author: String = "",
        @ColumnInfo(name = "block") var block: Boolean = false,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "duration") var duration: Int = 0,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "explicit") var explicit: String = "",
        @ColumnInfo(name = "image_url") var imageUrl: String = "",
        @ColumnInfo(name = "keywords") var keywords: List<String> = emptyList(),
        @ColumnInfo(name = "subtitle") var subTitle: String = "",
        @ColumnInfo(name = "summary") var summary: String = "",
        @ColumnInfo(name = "link") var link: String = "",
        @ColumnInfo(name = "publication_date") var pubDate: Date = Date(),
        @ColumnInfo(name = "title") var title: String = "",
        @ColumnInfo(name = "feed_url") var feedURL: String = "",
        @ColumnInfo(name = "download_state") var downloadState: Int = Item.DownloadState.STATE_NOT_DOWNLOADED
) : Serializable {
    companion object DownloadState {
        val STATE_NOT_DOWNLOADED = 0
        val STATE_DOWNLOADING = 1
        val STATE_DOWNLOADED = 2
    }
}
```

Feed

```
@Entity(foreignKeys = arrayOf(ForeignKey(
        entity = Owner::class,
        parentColumns = arrayOf("id"),
        childColumns = arrayOf("owner_id")
)))
data class Feed(
        @ColumnInfo(name = "url") @PrimaryKey var URL: String = "",
        @ColumnInfo(name = "copyright") var copyright: String? = null,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "description") var description: String? = null,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "itemGUIDs") var itemGUIDs: List<String> = emptyList(),
        @ColumnInfo(name = "author") var author: String? = null,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "block") var block: Boolean = false,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "categoryIds") var categoryIds: List<Int> = emptyList(),
        @ColumnInfo(name = "explicit") var explicit: Boolean = false,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "image_url") var imageUrl: String? = null,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "owner_id") var ownerId: Int = -1,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "subtitle") var subtitle: String? = null,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "summary") var summary: String? = null,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "language") var language: String = "",
        @ColumnInfo(name = "link") var link: String = "",
        @ColumnInfo(name = "title") var title: String = "",
        @ColumnInfo(name = "expiry") var expiry: Date = Date(),
        @ColumnInfo(name = "subscribed") var subscribed: Boolean = false
) : Serializable
```

Owner

```
@Entity
data class Owner(
        @ColumnInfo(name = "name") var name: String? = null,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "email") var email: String? = null
) : Serializable {
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Int = 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that when using `LiveData` with room, it immediately returns and so calling `LiveData.value` immediately gives `null` while it asynchronously gets the actual data to provide to Observers, and so can't be used as a drop in replacement if trying to convert from a non `LiveData` call. This is documented here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/LiveData.html#getValue()

> Returns the current value. Note that calling this method on a background thread does not guarantee that the latest value set will be received.